Stripe payment gateway error $config must be a string or an array
I a having error trying to access api key from .env file. I have tried several pages on internet to fix issue but it is not giving me any solution. I have tried to add services into services.php but nothing works out. I have also tried php artisan config:cache and also tried added into config/services.php
'stripe' => [
        'stripe_key' => env('STRIPE_KEY'),
        'secret_key' => env('STRIPE_SECRET'),
        ]
    ],

StripePaymentController.php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Stripe;
use Illuminate\View\View;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class StripePaymentController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function stripe():View {
        return view('stripe');
    }

    public function stripeCheckout(Request $request){
        $stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient(env('STRIPE_SECRET'));

        $redirectUrl = route('stripe.checkout.success').'?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}';

        $response = $stripe->checkout->sessions->create([
            'success_url' => $redirectUrl,

            'customer_email' => 'demo@quickairlink.com',

            'payment_method_type' => ['link','card'],

            'lne_items' => [
                [
                    'price_data' => [
                        'product_data' => [
                            'name' => $request->product,
                        ],
                    'unit_price' => 100 * $request->price,
                    'currency' => 'NZD',
                    ],
                    'quantity' => 1,
                ],

            ],
            'mode' => 'payment',
            'allow_promotion_codes' => true,
        ]);
        return redirect($response['url']);
    }

    public function stripeCheckoutSuccess(Request $request){
        $stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient(env('STRIPE_SECRET'));

        $response = $stripe->checkout->sessions->retrieve($request->session_id);

        return redirect()->route('stripe.index')->with('success','Payment Successful.');
    }
}



Please include the full error in your post as well as the ways you tried to fix this.

If you hard code the secret key in StripeClient, e.g. $stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient('sk_xxx'), does it work? If it does, this means that your env('STRIPE_SECRET') doesn't retrieve the secret key correctly from your .env file.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

Why create the services.php config file if you're not using it in your code?
You can change env('STRIPE_SECRET') to config('services.stripe.stripe_secret'). But yeah, it might be that the secret is not fetched properly causing errors. Try what @yuting said.

Yeah, never use env() outside of files in config/*.php in Laravel. I don't recall the instances, but there are multiple times where env('SOME_VALUE') will return null instead of the expected value from .env. Using env('SOME_VALUE') in a config/example.php file, then calling  config('example.some_value') will always return the configured value (which could still be null, but only if explicitly configured that way, or it's missing from .env or other environment sources such as CLI argument, etc.)

Change this line new \Stripe\StripeClient(env('STRIPE_SECRET')); to Stripe::setApiKey(env('STRIPE_SECRET'));

Thank you, I have tried it is giving me a syntax error

Your answer could be greatly improved if you explain why this would resolve OP's problem.

Because the stripe config key was not initiated using setApiKey
